# How to change vim cursor shape in different modes

Tags: vim, terminal, putty

I use vim under iTerm2 in Mac, or putty in windows. I want to see different vim cursor shape in different vim mode. I know gvim & macvim have this feature, and there's [an article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes) to figure out how to do that in gnome-terminal & KConsole. But I can't search out any solution in iTerm2 and Putty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This plugin](https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim) by the great Steve Losh takes care of iTerm2. I don't know about Putty.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin by Steve Losh (https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim) is a little buggy for some (adds weird characters in place of the cursor when you switch between tabs in iTerm2).

Adding this to your .vimrc works for me:

```
" Change cursor shape between insert and normal mode in iTerm2.app
if $TERM_PROGRAM =~ "iTerm"
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7" " Vertical bar in insert mode
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7" " Block in normal mode
endif
```

Credit goes to Erlend Hamberg:
http://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2014-03-09-change-vim-cursor-in-iterm.html

Answer (score 1):

I use [this plugin](https://github.com/jszakmeister/vim-togglecursor) since a long time, and it works perfectly with Konsole but it also supports a lot of terms.

The [documentation](https://github.com/jszakmeister/vim-togglecursor/blob/master/doc/togglecursor.txt#L18) says:

> Currently supported terminals are iTerm2 for the Mac (version 1.0.0.20130602
>   beta or better is required), VTE3 based terminals (including gnome-terminal),
>   and KDE's Konsole. The xterm console is partially supported as well. Older 
>   xterm's didn't support the line cursor, so this plugin currently sets the 
>   cursor to underline instead.
>
> Older versions of VTE3 based terminals (before v0.39) do not support changing 
>   the cursor via escape sequences and are not supported.  On unsupported 
>   terminals, Vim's default behavior is left unaltered.
>
> The plugin also supports tmux, and will change your cursor inside a tmux
>   session too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not install any plugins,you can change the [putty reconfiguration]->Window->Appearance -> [Cursor appearance] ->[Vertical line],

it is more convenient.

And I think it is unnessary to change the vim cursor,because it will hardly find the cursor if you change the shape!